# Backward stability of the SVD

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, numerical-linear-algebra

I am interested in the backward stability of numerical algorithms for computation of the singular value decomposition (SVD). Specifically, I am interested in the following result:

> **Backward stabile computation of the SVD.** Assume $\operatorname{poly}(n) u < 1$. There exists an algorithm which takes input $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ runs in $\mathcal{O}(n^3 \log^\beta (n/u))$ (for some $\beta \ge0$) floating point operations of precision $u$ that produces matrices $\hat{U},\hat{\Sigma},\hat{V}$ such that there exist $\Delta A,\Delta U,\Delta V$ for which $$A+\Delta A = (\hat{U}+\Delta U)\hat{\Sigma}(\hat{V}+\Delta V)^\top$$ is an exact singular value decomposition of $A+\Delta A$ and $\|\Delta U\|,\|\Delta V\|,\|\Delta A\|/\|A\| \le \operatorname{poly}(n)u$.

Here, I am happy for $\operatorname{poly}(n)$ to be any nonnegative polynomial function in $n$.

**Is there any reference in the literature for this theorem that provides a complete proof (including references to any needed results)?**

The literature contains [many references](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/0728076) to this statement being "well-known". The [classic reference of Golub and van Loan](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=5U-l8U3P-VUC&oi=fnd&pg=PP1&dq=golub%20and%20van%20loan&ots=7-KvNo_Pdn&sig=B9HCuLPu2RctMwYaWQ7ldlbLrac#v=onepage&q=golub%20and%20van%20loan&f=false) states that the conclusion of this theorem "can be shown" (section 5.4.1) for the Golub–Kahan–Reinsch algorithm. I was unable to find a proof in standard books by [Demmel](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/book/10.1137/1.9781611971446) and [Trefethen and Bau](https://books.google.com/books?id=4Mou5YpRD_kC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) and [original](https://people.duke.edu/%7Ehpgavin/SystemID/References/Golub+Reinsch-NM-1970.pdf) [references](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0702016?casa_token=xleddypadT0AAAAA:cHOfcDGD2XJnO6yAWaZmLQuyPo5os-eDVVGcNsnpiYU_snJqffo3A9WB1WIFwGZF2SQlW7a2EA).

Recent work in theoretical computer science (see, e.g., [this note](http://arxiv.org/abs/2305.10575)) has brought renewed attention to the complexity of core linear algebra problems. In [one of the papers](http://arxiv.org/abs/2205.06810) in this recent effort, they state that the finite-precision analysis of shifted QR iteration (closely related to the Golub–Kahan–Reinsch algorithm) was unsolved (see section 1.2).

To be clear, my intentions are to find a reference which establishes the unassailable truth of this (purported) theorem as a statement of mathematics. I am well-aware that existing algorithms such as Golub–Kahan–Reinsch appear to obey the conditions of this theorem in practice.